# Qtwebkit doesn't load javascript websites

Tags: javascript, qt5, html, pyqt5, qtwebkit

I need to load this website into my application using PyQt5 QtWebkit.
https://banggia-as.vndirect.com.vn/chart/?symbol=GAS

For some reasons, I need to use QwebKit instead of Qwebengine. I have tried opening the website the normal way. However, all I get is a blank page. Plz help. I think I'm missing some javascript features to make it work.Thanks

```
browser = QWebView()
browser.load(QUrl("https://banggia-as.vndirect.com.vn/chart/?symbol=GAS"))
browser.show()
```

This only show a blank page.

Comment: What Qt version are you on?

Comment: I have the same problem using QWebEngine on 5.8. Did you find an answer to this?